# How do I know at runtime what event listeners are registered to a component in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm trying to debug an issue I have with an event being fired two times. I'm just curious and want to know if there is any way I could know how many event listeners are registered to a component at runtime.

Say for example I have a button, and using some code in the browser's console I'm able to see all the event listeners attached to the button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing it, may not be elegant but worked for me. The only requirement is to have at least a portion of the selector query, works well if you give an itemId.

Just execute the following function, passing an itemId as selector.

```
>> function showListeners(selector) {
     var regexp = new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+selector+'(?=\\s|$)'), 
     bus = Ext.app.EventDomain.instances.component.bus;

     for(var i in bus) {   
       var selectors = Object.keys(bus[i]);
       for(var j in selectors) {
         if(regexp.test(selectors[j])) {
           console.log("selector: '" + selectors[j] + 
                       "'\n on -> " + i + " : " + Object.keys(bus[i][selectors[j]])[0]);
         }
       }
     }
   }

>> showListeners('#wizardWindow')
```

That will return something like this (just an example):

```
> selector: '#mainContainer #wizardWindow'
  on -> beforerender : home.WizardController
> selector: '#mainContainer #wizardWindow'
  on -> afterrender : home.WizardController
```

It will basically tell which controller has an event listener registered for the given component (if found).

I hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that, but you can ask if there is a listener for a concrete event using the **hasListener(eventName)** method: http://docs.extjs.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-hasListener

Answer (score 0):

You can see all event listeners attach to your DOM in the DOM explorer of dev tools (at least in Firefox).

[image: 'ev' button]

Click the `ev` button.

Comment: The idea was to work with ExtJS components, not at the DOM level. But thanks for the tip,

Answer (score 0):

[Sencha Labs](http://www.senchalabs.org/) has published a chrome extension called [App Inspector for Sencha](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-inspector-for-sencha/pbeapidedgdpniokbedbfbaacglkceae?hl=en). The tool gives you a lot of extensive information about your sencha app. It also provides an event recording facility which will capture any events triggered and what component triggered those events. You can take a look and see how useful it is. I find it helpful to a large extent. [image]

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't hear about this chrome extension until now. It does provide a lot of useful information! But I'm afraid it does not provide an answer to my specific need, which is to know how many listeners are attached to any given component. I've been playing arround with it and cannot find any way of getting that information.